# Minus one dollar or minus one dollars?

Tags: grammatical-number

Which is correct English, "you have *minus one dollar* in your account" or "you have *minus one dollars* in your account"?

Is the rule general?

For example, which is correct, "you have minus one diamond in your account" or "you have minus one diamonds in your account"?

I note that [number-word.calculators.ro](http://number-word.calculators.ro/write-USD-currency-numbers-in-words.php) gives "minus one dollar", and that of course "you have minus two dollar in your account" is wrong while "you have minus two dollars in your account" is correct. Further "please minus one dollar from my account" is correct, while "please minus one dollars from my account" is not.

Comment: Making the noun a negative doesn't change the subject-verb agreement. Minus one dollar, just like (positive) one dollar is still singular.

Comment: I carefully watched all suggested possible related questions as I typed and searched here before, but it seems "one" and "1" are not identified by the search engine. Thanks for the help.